# Any known performance difference between Java & C# BigQuery Client API?

Tags: java, c#, google-bigquery, google-api-dotnet-client

we are recently switching from Java to c# and we found big difference in performance of the data stream API:

```
C#: await BigQueryService.Tabledata.InsertAll(request, ProjectId, DataSetId, TableId).ExecuteAsync();
Java: BigQueryService.tabledata.insertAll(ProjectId, DataSetId, TableId,request).execute();
```

during our test, we got less than 25 responses within a second with C# API call but we can get averagely 35 response a second with Java API.
 (we record a "request send" log right before we call the above APIs and record a "response get" log right after we get response object from the above APIs. And, we did the test on the same machine and with the same collection of data)

**Edit**

Well, I dig more into API source code, traced into it and then wrote a simple call that directly uses HttpClient. Here's how the call looks like (not perfect, but just intend to break down the time cost as deep as I could):

```
string requestUri = BaseUri + string.Format("/projects/{0}/datasets/{1}/tables/{2}/insertAll", projectId, datasetId,tableId);
var serializedObject = BigQueryService.SerializeObject(request);
HttpContent content = new StringContent(serializedObject, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
content = await CompressAsync(content);
using (HttpRequestMessage httpRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, requestUri)
{
     Version = Version.Parse("1.1"),
     Content = content
})
{
     Stopwatch sw1 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
     await _staticCredential.InterceptAsync(httpRequest, ct).ConfigureAwait(false);
     sw1.Stop();
     Stopwatch sw2 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
     HttpResponseMessage returnMsg =  await HttpClient.SendAsync(httpRequest,ct);
     // HttpResponseMessage returnMsg = await HttpClient.PostAsync(requestUri,content,ct);
     sw2.Stop();
     Logger.Trace("Credential.InterceptAsync~{0}~HttpClient.SendAsync~{1}", sw1.ElapsedMilliseconds, sw2.ElapsedMilliseconds);
     return returnMsg;
 }
```

The "StringContent" here is averagely 160KB, while the compressed content is averagely 16KB. I'm on 64-bit Windows Server 2012 R2, with two 4-cores processor, 24GB RAM,  1 Gbps network connection.

According to stopwatch result, average time elapse per successful httpclient call is above 10 seconds, and can reach a burst high of above 40 seconds. It's somehow does not make much sense to me, but cannot think of a reason..

Comment: The .NET Bigquery API version: Google.Apis.Bigquery.v2 1.9.2.2210

Comment: Can you add more details about the machine, Windows version, etc? what happen if you use the non async version. Just "Execute"?

Comment: @peleyal Thanks for your suggestion, I updated more details above.  I didn't use non-async version, because I'm on async throughout my whole solution, I don't think use sync version is a right choice.